# How to use D3 to load csv, display table and style it with bootstrap in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, csv, d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to load up csv files using D3 and display them using Bootstrap library. The script works and displays the table, however, the Bootstrap styling is not applied.

Here is my code that I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
            d3.text("data.csv", function(data) {
                var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

                var container = d3.select("body")
                    .append("div").attr("class","container")
                    .append("table").attr("class","table table-hover")

                    .selectAll("tr")
                        .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                        .append("tr")

                    .selectAll("td")
                        .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                        .append("td")
                        .text(function(d) { return d; });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When checking the output in the Elements in Developer Tools it generates consistent with the one presented in this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_hover&stacked=h).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `styling not applied`, I assume you are referring to the `table-hover` class.  For that to work you need a proper table with a `<tbody>` attribute:

```
var container = d3.select("body")
  .append("div").attr("class","container")
  .append("table").attr("class","table table-hover")
  .append("tbody");
```

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //d3.text("data.csv", function(data) {

    var data = "header1,header2,header3\r\na,b,c\r\nd,e,f\r\n";

    var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

    var container = d3.select("body")
      .append("div").attr("class", "container")
      .append("table").attr("class", "table table-hover")
      .append("tbody")

    .selectAll("tr")
      .data(parsedCSV).enter()
      .append("tr")

    .selectAll("td")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      }).enter()
      .append("td")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d;
      });
    //});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```